# Problem with setting up a second domain on a single LAMP server

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd

Host: GNU/Linux Debian 9 Stretch ([testing](https://www.debian.org/releases/testing/)).

Usage: New LAMP server with HTTPS; (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP, [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)).

---

Software versions:

- Apache version; **IN USE** for both domains:

  ```
  apt-cache policy apache2
  ```

  Tells me:

  > ```
  > apache2:
  >   Installed: 2.4.25-3
  >   Candidate: 2.4.25-3
  >   Version table:
  >  *** 2.4.25-3 500
  >         500 http://ftp.sh.cvut.cz/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
  >         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
  > ```
- MySQL version; **UNUSED**, just prepared:

  ```
  apt-cache policy mariadb-client mariadb-server
  ```

  Tells me:

  > ```
  > mariadb-client:
  >   Installed: 10.1.22-3
  >   Candidate: 10.1.22-3
  >   Version table:
  >  *** 10.1.22-3 500
  >         500 http://ftp.sh.cvut.cz/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
  >         500 http://ftp.sh.cvut.cz/debian testing/main i386 Packages
  >         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
  >
  > mariadb-server:
  >   Installed: 10.1.22-3
  >   Candidate: 10.1.22-3
  >   Version table:
  >  *** 10.1.22-3 500
  >         500 http://ftp.sh.cvut.cz/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
  >         500 http://ftp.sh.cvut.cz/debian testing/main i386 Packages
  >         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
  > ```
- PHP version; **UNUSED**, just prepared:

  > ```
  > php7.0:
  >   Installed: 7.0.16-3
  >   Candidate: 7.0.16-3
  >   Version table:
  >  *** 7.0.16-3 500
  >         500 http://ftp.sh.cvut.cz/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
  >         500 http://ftp.sh.cvut.cz/debian testing/main i386 Packages
  >         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
  > ```
- Let’s Encrypt version; **IN USE** for both domains:

  ```
  certbot --version
  ```

  Tells me:

  > ```
  > certbot 0.10.2
  > ```

---

**What is working:**

- One VirtualHost (domain) works perfectly fine on Apache2 with the simplest html file with title "Apache2 Debian Default Page: It works":

  https://www.zalohovaniburian.cz

  [HT Bridge](https://www.htbridge.com/ssl/?id=eddba385c2f8f513d65a3d412850161da2c7eb1c7c7b9b0ccd685781468f3e4c) SSL test result looks fine.

**What is not working:**

- A new domain I have just added, and I believe the same way, to Apache2; Despite trying for hours, I can't seem to be able to identify the problem, is telling me:

  > ```
  > You don't have permission to access / on this server.
  > ```

  https://www.pavelstriz.cz

  [HT Bridge](https://www.htbridge.com/ssl/?id=9d754b85ce83c2ef15e83b5e283c3dc851a313b63c50aaa2bfa3f1133104799c) SSL test result looks fine.

So, I just ruled out a problem with SSL. A problem with connection to these domains in general. They connect just fine.

---

To mention at least some points, that I've done so far:

```
chown -R newUser:www-data public_html/
chmod -R 644 public_html/
```

Whereas, I added this user to the `www-data` group, proof:

```
groups newUser
```

Gives output:

> ```
> newUser : newUser www-data
> ```

---

Any hints or clues appreciated. If you want to know some detailed information, please comment, I will edit the question shortly after. I might even post the VirtualHost file(s), if that would be of any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours I finally figured it out.

I completely forgot about the permissions to the `public_html` directory.

Ownership and group have been set fine.

Suffice to say, that it was a mistake on my part.

Solution was to change permissions from this state:

```
drw-r--r-- 2 newUser www-data 4.0K Apr 13 22:13 public_html/
```

To this one:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 newUser www-data 4.0K Apr 13 22:13 public_html/
```